# How to create derived entities (with their own attributes) based on the attributes values of another entity

Tags: uml, entity-relationship, data-modeling

I have a Real Estate Property entity.

I have a Real Estate Property Category entity with attributes :

- number
- type (house, appartement, studio, field, land, office,
  commercial)
- offer (for rent, for sale)
- price
- surface

Depending on the values of type and offer I need to create specialized entities with their own attributes.

Examples:

for type = house or appartement

- number of rooms
- number of garages
- equiped kitchen
- garden surface

for type = house

- number of floors

for type = not field (every types but field)

- description

for type = office or commercial

- surface
- number of spaces

How can I describe these specializations in an ER Diagram (Peter Chen Notation) and translate it afterwords in a class diagram.

**Edit** See attached picture
[image]

Comment: Try this: create a diagram on your own to your best knowledge. Then post is here and ask if it's ok. You need to place the diagram on a public server and link it until you have enough reputation to directly include images here.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Thomas. Here is a link to an ER diagram with just the necessary entities: [Specialization by predicate on Gliffy](http://www.gliffy.com/go/publish/7655311). I do not know if this is correct. In case it is, how could I apply these conditions in a class diagram to make a kind of conditional specialization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is almost correct. The only thing is that you need to surround the constraints in braces

> A Constraint is shown as a text string in braces ({}) according to the following BNF:
>
> `<constraint> ::= ‘{‘ [ <name> ‘:’ ] <Boolean-expression> ‘ }’`

(from Superstructures 2.1.1 p. 61)

Also you should remove the `if`.

Unfortunately Superstructures is a very poor document. I was not able to locate the definition of `<Boolean-expression>` but I would use `==` instead of `=` as in most C-like languages. So one of your constraints should read

```
{Property.Category.Offer == "for rent"}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, Thomas. I will add the braces and correct the syntax.